# Changing Language don't clear error message

Tags: reactjs, zod

I'm making a form with a zod validation schema.
My app can switch language.
But when I do it, the error message doesn't reset and stay displayed. I think I can use a useEffect, but I don't know where to do it and how.

```
export const phoneSchemaWithValidation = createUniqueFieldSchema(
  z.string().refine((data) => validatePhone(data).isValid, {
    message: 'Invalid phone number',
  }),
  'phone',
);
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { PhoneInput, validatePhone } from 'react-international-phone';
import { cn } from '@shared/utils';
import { useDescription, useTsController } from '@ts-react/form';

// import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useStyles } from '../../../../hooks/useStyles';
import ErrorMessage from './ErrorMessage';
import Label from './Label';
import { inputClassNames } from './mapping';

import 'react-international-phone/style.css';

export function PhoneField(props: { required?: boolean }) {
  const { field, error } = useTsController<string>();
  const { label } = useDescription();

  const { rounded } = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <Label label={label} error={error} required={props.required} />
      <PhoneInput
        defaultCountry="fr"
        // defaultCountry={countryCode}
        value={field.value}
        onChange={field.onChange}
        className={cn(rounded, {
          'ring-1 ring-red-500': error?.errorMessage,
        })}
        inputClassName={inputClassNames}
      />
      <ErrorMessage {...error} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't not understand if you meant switching locale for the phone input or for the whole app. This solution is for the phone input, but if it's for the whole app you have to show what package you're using for translating.

This might also not be the best solution because it requires adding another state. But I think it should work.

1. Add a state for selected country

```
 const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState<string>("fr")
```

2. Update your onChange handler to check if selected country has changed.

```
onChange={(phone, meta) => {
  if(meta.country.iso2 !== selectedCountry) {
    // reset error here
  }
  setSelectedCountry(meta.country.iso2);
  field.onChange(phone)
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. In fact, If the input is required and the user click on send, It will display an error message. But, when I change the language, the error message stay displayed. I want it to disappear when switching language